# Laravel filtering one to many relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have `Product` and `Category` models tied one to many.How to filter Products by category? In template i have

```php
 <a href="{{ route('product.productsByCategory', $category->id) }}" class="list-group-item">{{ $category->name }}</a>
```

How to write function to filter Products with Category?

```php
 public function productsByCategory($category_id){
   $products = Product:: ????
   return view("layouts._productsByCategory", compact("products"));
```

Answer is

```php
$products = Product::where('category_id', $category_id)->get();
```

Comment: It's probably better if you mark the answer is accepted instead of answering inside the question.

Comment: Yes, but i accepted one answer today, i have to wait few more minutes to be able accept another one. Stackoverflow rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$products = Product::where('category_id', $category_id)->get();
```

or

```
$products = Product::whereHas('category', function($q) use ($category_id) {
               $q->where('id', $category_id);
           });
```

assuming you set `category` relationship in `Product` model.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to go via the category:

```
public function productsByCategory($category_id){
    return view("layouts._productsByCategory", [
       'products' => Category::with('products')->find($category_id)->products
    ]);
}
```